# fullpage js — little annoying mouse cursor change

Tags: javascript, cursor, fullpage.js

I'm using fullpage.js and I split the screen in half. When you click in the top —half you scroll up, and when you click in the down part you'll scroll down.

I hate the fact that during the transition the mouse cursor changes from s-resize or n-resize to the normal cursor.

Any solutions?

You can have a look here: http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html
and if you click the "moveSection..." buttons it acts the same way.

**JS**

```
         $('#up').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
        });

        $('#down').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
        });
```

**CSS**

```
#down {
width:100%;
height:50%;
top:50%;
position:fixed;
z-index:10000;
cursor:s-resize;
}

#up {
width:100%;
height:50%;
top:0;
position:fixed;
z-index:10000;
cursor:n-resize;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a jsfiddle so that we can take a look at it?

Comment: I don't know why in the Fiddle works correctly though :( https://jsfiddle.net/gg6wcrsn/

Comment: It is hard to help then... I also don't know what you refer to when I look at  http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html

Comment: @FedericoFerrari what about including all the necessary plugin files in the fiddle plus the fullpage.js initialization? In SO things are simple: no reproduction less answers.

Comment: I've updated it but it still works correctly. If you check the website thought, there it isn't working correctly, like in my website.

https://jsfiddle.net/gg6wcrsn/1/